# Date Difference Averaging and Grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have the following table:

```
User | Date_start | Date_End | Task  
----------------------------------------  
 Al  | 1/11/17    | 1/14/17  | Dishes
 Al  | 1/09/17    | 1/15/17  | Paint
 Al  | 1/11/17    | 1/14/17  | Dishes
 Al  | 1/18/17    | 1/20/17  | Paint
Todd | 1/11/17    | 1/14/17  | Dishes
 Al  | 1/11/17    | 1/21/17  | Dishes
Todd | 1/10/17    | 1/17/17  | Paint
Todd | 1/11/17    | 1/14/17  | Dishes
Todd | 1/11/17    | 1/14/17  | Paint
 Al  | 1/11/17    | NULL     | Dishes
```

What I am trying to do is average the days to complete a task in the task column
and distinctly group them by task. However if a record hasn't been completed yet (as evidenced by 'null') I want to exclude this record from the avg calculation. Additionally I am trying to uniquely count them by the task (again, ignoring records with a 'null' value for date_end). I am looking to get an output like this (the "avg" numbers are definitely off and are only for demonstration):

```
User | Count_of_Task | AVG_Time_to_Finish_In_Days | Task  
-----------------------------------------------------------  
 Al  |        3      |           4.2              | Dishes
 Al  |        2      |           4.0              | Paint
Todd |        2      |           2.6              | Dishes
Todd |        2      |           6.1              | Paint
```

I am using the below SQL:

```
Select s.user,
     COUNT(s.task) as count_of_task,
     AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,s.date_start,s.date_end)*1.0) as avg_time_to_finish_in_days,
     s.task
FROM dbo.stuff s
WHERE S.DATE_END IS NOT null
GROUP by s.task,
   s.user
HAVING AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,s.date_start,s.date_end)*1.0) <> 0
  and COUNT(s.task) <> 0
```

This SQL is not grouping the task correctly and is truncating the avg time to finish, giving me avg's that only have 0 for decimal places ( i.e., 6.000000).

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server???

Comment: Just sql-server. I'll remove that other tag

Comment: So, you need a 'WHERE Date_end IS NOT NULL' in there.

Comment: `and COUNT(s.task) as count_of_task <> 0` you cant use `AS` in the `having` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding a WHERE clause should be sufficient

```
Select s.user,
     COUNT(s.task) as count_of_task,
     AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,s.date_start,s.date_end)*1.0) as avg_time_to_finish_in_days,
     s.task
FROM dbo.stuff s
WHERE s.date_end IS NOT NULL -- this should be sufficient
GROUP by s.task, s.user
```

Note that in SQL Server you can use both WHERE and HAVING with GROUP BY.
WHERE acts before grouping and HAVING after grouping.

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @YourTable table ([User] varchar(25),Date_start  date,Date_End date,Task  varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Al','1/11/17','1/14/17','Dishes'),
('Al','1/09/17','1/15/17','Paint'),
('Al','1/11/17','1/14/17','Dishes'),
('Al','1/18/17','1/20/17','Paint'),
('Todd','1/11/17','1/14/17','Dishes'),
('Al','1/11/17','1/21/17','Dishes'),
('Todd','1/10/17','1/17/17','Paint'),
('Todd','1/11/17','1/14/17','Dishes'),
('Todd','1/11/17','1/14/17','Paint'),
('Al','1/11/17',NULL,'Dishes')

Select [User]
      ,Count_Of_Task = count(*)
      ,AVG_Time_to_Finish_In_Days  = convert(decimal(10,1),avg(datediff(DAY,Date_start,Date_End)+0.0))
      ,Task
 From  @YourTable 
 Where Date_End is not null
 Group By [User],Task
 Order by [User],Task
```

Returns

```
User    Count_Of_Task   AVG_Time_to_Finish_In_Days  Task
Al      3               5.3                         Dishes
Al      2               4.0                         Paint
Todd    2               3.0                         Dishes
Todd    2               5.0                         Paint
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!